# Agregue una nueva opción a una selección con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Primero al hacer clic select numero para cambios de valor en el elemento de registro, ahí está el problema, muestra la foto ese color amarillo (fue agregar otro mas seleccione). Necesito un valor de una opcion "seleccione" no mas.

Como puedo recorrer las opciones del select?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select[title="numero"]').change(function () {
   
  loadRegistro(); 
  
 });
  
 loadRegistro();
  
});

function loadRegistro(){
  
 var htmlRegistro = $('select[title="registro"] option');
 var htmlOptions = '<option value="">--Seleccione--</option>';
  
 $(htmlRegistro).each(function(name, val) { 

 htmlOptions += "<option value='"+val.text+"'>"+val.text+"</option>";

 });
  
 $('select[title="registro"]').html(htmlOptions);
 $('select[title="registro"]').val("");
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numero" title="numero">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="registro" title="registro">
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: es necesario que el `option` 13, 14 y 15 estén siempre??

Comment: @Travv si asi es, pero option value seleccione repite. y solo uno valor seleccione.

Comment: haber si te entiendo, si en numero pones 1 , tiene que salir en registro --seleccione-- 13,14,15 ,,   pero si pones 3 saldría --seleccione--, --seleccione--, --seleccione--, 13,14,15 ?

Comment: @Travv cuando numero pongo 1, solo tiene que salir en registro --seleccione -- 13,14,15 y despues renova otro numero pongo 2,  mismo tiene que salir en registro --seleccione -- 13,14,15 y ultimo renova otro numero pongo 3,  mismo tiene que salir en registro --seleccione -- 13,14,15. el problema es que solo pasa mal saldría --seleccione--, --seleccione--, --seleccione--,etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da ya que cada vez que cambias de opción en el `select name="numero"` copias TODOS los `option` del `select name="registro"`

### Solución 1

En lugar de copiar todos `option`, podrías usar el [selector de atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) para seleccionar solo los `option` que tengan `value`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[title="numero"]').change(function() {
    loadRegistro();
  });

  loadRegistro();
});

function loadRegistro() {

  // AQUI Seleccionamos solo los options que tienen value
  var htmlRegistro = $('select[title="registro"] option[value]');
  var htmlOptions = '<option>--Seleccione--</option>';

  $(htmlRegistro).each(function(name, val) {
    htmlOptions += "<option value='" + val.text + "'>" + val.text + "</option>";
  });

  $('select[title="registro"]').html(htmlOptions);
  $('select[title="registro"]').val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numero" title="numero">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="registro" title="registro">
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

### Solución 2

Podrías simplemente agregar `<option>--Seleccione--</option>` en el `HTML`.

#### Ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[title="numero"]').change(function() {
    loadRegistro();
  });

  loadRegistro();
});

function loadRegistro() {
  $('select[title="registro"]').val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numero" title="numero">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="registro" title="registro">
  <!-- AQUI agregamos el option -->
  <option>--Seleccione--</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

---

## Update

Dado a que [has modificado tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141534/revisions) y el código de la misma...

### Solución

Mientras copias los `option`, podrías verificar si el `value != ''`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[title="numero"]').change(function() {
    loadRegistro();
  });

  loadRegistro();
});

function loadRegistro() {

  var htmlRegistro = $('select[title="registro"] option[value]');
  var htmlOptions = '<option value="">--Seleccione--</option>';

  $(htmlRegistro).each(function(name, val) {
    // AQUI  Validamos el value del option
    if (val.value == '') {
      return;
    }
    htmlOptions += "<option value='" + val.text + "'>" + val.text + "</option>";
  });

  $('select[title="registro"]').html(htmlOptions);
  $('select[title="registro"]').val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numero" title="numero">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="registro" title="registro">
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, entiendo claro.

Comment: se me olvido de decir, ya ha modificado tu codigo, yo agrego el valor,  var htmlOptions = '<option value="">Seleccione Registro</option>'; y primero solucion 1, puedes ejecutar para prueba.

Comment: estas ahi???????

Comment: @DiegoSagredo, has modificado el escenario, por lo que la solución 1 ya no aplica. Este tipo de cosas son las que no debes hacer a la hora de formular tu pregunta.

Comment: @DiegoSagredo, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: entiendo claro. gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se si te he entendido bien, pero creo que lo que intentas hacer esto

```
<select name="numero" title="numero">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="registro" title="registro">
        <option value="-1">--Seleccione--</option>
</select>
```

Dale un value negativo a tu opción por defecto y en el bucle compara el valor, si es -1 no lo añades y listo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[title="numero"]').change(function () {

        loadRegistro();

    });

    loadRegistro();

});

function loadRegistro(){

    var htmlRegistro = $('select[title="registro"] option');


    var htmlOptions = '';

    $(htmlRegistro).each(function(name, val) {
        if(val != -1){
            htmlOptions += "<option value='"+val.text+"'>"+val.text+"</option>";
        }

    });


    htmlOptions += "<option value='13'>13</option>";
    htmlOptions += "<option value='14'>14</option>";
    htmlOptions += "<option value='15'>15</option>";

    $('select[title="registro"]').html(htmlOptions);
    $('select[title="registro"]').val("");

}
```